# What does this "__init__" do in this code?

Tags: python, lambda

I don't understand the following code:

```
def __init__(self, create_context=None):
    self._events = []
    self._create_context = (
        create_context
        if create_context is not None else
        lambda *_: nop_context
    )

class nop_context(object):
    """A nop context manager.
    """
    def __enter__(self):
        pass

    def __exit__(self, *excinfo):
        pass
```

I know self._create_context is a generator, but what will self._create_context hold after the **init** is executed? What does the lambda in the generator expression do?

Comment: Is the `__init__` function for a different class, or do you have things in the wrong order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self._create_context` is not a generator, unless the value passed in the `create_context` parameter happens to be a generator. Otherwise the parentheses are just wrapping the expression so that it can span multiple lines, presumably to improve readability.

All this function is doing, however, is to apply a default value to `self._create_context`. It is basically the same as this:

```
class nop_context(object):
    def __enter__(self):
        pass
    def __exit__(self, *excinfo):
        pass

def __init__(self, create_context=lambda *_: nop_context):
    self._events = []
    self._create_context = create_context
```

The `*_` is simply a way of allowing the function to accept an arbitrary number of arguments. I'd prefer to see `*args` in place of `*_` because it is a more recognisable Python idiom.

Note: the way that I have shown above creates a single lambda function for the class when the `__init__` method is defined. Strictly speaking functions are mutable. This means that any change to the function object will affect all instances of the respective class. It's similar to when a mutable default such as a list is used. While it can be a problem in the case of a list, it is not at all common to modify a function, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Answer (score 1):

That code is confusingly terse. I'd have used something far more explicit.

```
def __init__(self, create_context=None):
    if create_context:
        self._create_context = create_context
    else:
        self._create_context = lambda *_: nop_context
```

Arguably I should have honoured the same `if create_context is not None:`, depends on what create_context normally is (I'm assuming it's some callable that can be called later to lazily create the context).

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to tell if you put it in two lines:

```
create_context if create_context is not None
else lambda *_: nop_context
```

(Note: that is not valid syntax to put it like I just did)

`self._create_context` will be `create_context` if `create_context` is anything other than `None`, but if it is `None`, then we need to use a default.  The default in this case is a lambda function that takes `*_` as arguments, and returns `nop_context`.  `*_` may be a little confusing at first, but it is the same as `*args`: it means we can take any number of arguments.  We will store those arguments in a tuple called `_`.  There `_` is used because we aren't going to use those arguments.  Whatever they are, we will always return `nop_context`.